# Credentials from Active Directory stored securely in report server SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, active-directory

I've got problem with setting credentials in my report on SSRS as "Stored securely in the report server".

I've created a user "reportviewer" as active directory user

When I set credentials in my report in SSRS, they don't work.

What is more I've got problem with SQL Server User Login not only this Windows User Login.

I'm using SQL Server Express with advanced services

These are my current settings from AD and SQL Server. (I apologise for not the best image quality).

Settings AD and SQL Server

[image: Settings AD and SQL Server]

These are settings from SSRS.

SSRS settings - credentials

[image: SSRS settings - credentials]

Can anybody give me any clues what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a reportviewer user account in SQL Server, and give it the relevant permissions.

Then use that login and password for your RS reports.

There should be no need to create an AD account for reports.

Comment: The point is that I've created SQL user, and I've set permissions that in my opinion were relevant and they worked fine in similar projects but not in this one. Due to the fact I will be able to access the database next Tuesday, I'll try this solution once again then with SQL user login as you suggested. But in my opinion, there should be no difference between windows user login and SQL user login. It's awkward.

Comment: I've created a new SQL user once again, gave him appropriate permissions and it worked. I have no idea why it didn't work before. Thanks for your help.